# How to pass parameters and load the wsdl using Web Service Consumer in Mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el, mule-component

Hi I am working with Mule Studio and i just want to know how can i pass the parameters and call the particular Operation from SOAP using the Web Service Consumer component.

[image]

Payload i am setting as `#[{'Orlando','United States'}]` for the operation `GetWeather`

The sample SOAP service i am using is [LINK](http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?WSDL)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XyZcI1_MbOo) you have a video demonstration on how to do it.

[Here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Web+Service+Consumer) the manual Page, and [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Web+Service+Consumer+Example) an example.

If you don't want to use DataMapper, I would recommend to use a [CXF client](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Consuming+Web+Services+with+CXF) or to write a specilized [connector](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Creating+a+Connector+for+a+SOAP+Service+Via+CXF+Client).

If you still want to use the web service consumer no matter what, you just need to set a payload with the body (this is just the body, not the whole envelope) of the operation. You are passing a JSON, this more than probably won't work. You need to convert it to a proper XML SOAP request body.

Comment: video is awesome but i dont want to use data mapper and i want to pass the values in the selected operation how to do that..

Comment: I am updating question plz have a look at once i need something similar to this plz recommend some thing whether this is possible or not

Comment: I have updated, however I can't create the body for you.

Comment: Thanks but i need a solution for dynamically passing the payload value to the web service consumer , is their any way....