# How to put web service consumer configuration in properties file in Mulesoft?

Tags: web-services, mule, mule-studio

I want to put the parameters of web service consumer in a properties file. I know how to use properties file in mule. ${myWSDLlocation} in the configuration dialogue box does not do anything. I looked into [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27151978/how-to-pass-parameters-and-load-the-wsdl-using-web-service-consumer-in-mule), but could not solve it.
[image: web service consumer flow]

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution.. This is what I did:

1. Dragged and dropped ws-consumer in flow
2. Configured it using the UI
3. Added properties file and defined key-value pairs in it - [the usual way](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/deploying-to-multiple-environments)
4. Then edited the `<ws:consumer-config>` tag using ${keyNameHere}

Answer (score 0):

First be sure you have property placeholders defined. Below is the syntax where a config.properties file has been defined to be used and it is placed in src/main/resources directory of your project.

Now in you properties file you can define the stuffs like below

implementation.url=http://abc-cdc.com

This URL can be accessed from web service consumer application using below.

ws:consumer-config doc:name="Web Service Consumer" name="Web_Service_Consumer" connectorConfig="HTTPS_Request_Configuration" wsdlLocation="ServiceWSDL/Manager.wsdl" serviceAddress="![p['implementation.url']]" port="ManagerSOAPPort" service="ManagerService"

In above example I am using only serviceAddress from config.properties file. Please let me know how it goes.